# How do I process data in the form of nested array objects on json?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, nested

On this occasion I have a problem in making data table. the data that I will manage is a nested array of json objects so I hope to find the answer here :)

This is an example of a code snippet that I could use.

```
{{ user?.referredUser?.list[0]?.status }}
```

But this is not suitable because later this list of users will continue to grow along with the number of users.

```
<table class="table table-hover table-condensed" id="DataTable" [mfData]="referred" #mf="mfDataTable"
         [mfRowsOnPage]="25" [(mfSortBy)]="sortBy" [(mfSortOrder)]="sortOrder">
           <thead>
               <tr>
                   <th class="v-align-middle" style="width:10%">
                        <mfDefaultSorter>Name</mfDefaultSorter>
                   </th>
                   <th class="v-align-middle" style="width:10%">
                           <mfDefaultSorter>Status</mfDefaultSorter>
                   </th>
                   <!-- <th class="v-align-middle" style="color: #369; width:10%;" data-hide="phone,tablet"> Action
                   </th> -->
               </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody>
             <!-- <tr *ngFor="let user.referredUser.list[0] of mf.data; let i = index"> -->
             <tr>
                 <!-- <td class="v-align-middle"><span class="muted">
                 <img src="{{ helper.getImageUrl(appConfig, user) }}" class="list-logo">
                 {{ user?.referredUser?.list[0]?.name | titlecase }}</span></td> -->
                 <td class="v-align-middle"><span class="muted">
                 <input type="image" img src="{{ helper.getImageUrl(appConfig, user) }}" class="list-logo" data-toggle="tooltip" [routerLink]="['/user/' + user?.referredUser?.list[0]?.id + '/listdetail']"><br>
                 {{ user?.referredUser?.list[0]?.name | titlecase }}</span></td>
                 <td class="v-align-middle"><span class="muted"> {{ user?.referredUser?.list[0]?.status }} </span></td>
                 <!-- <td class="v-align-middle"><a class="muted" data-toggle="tooltip" [routerLink]="['/user/' + user?.referredUser?.list[0]?.id + '/listdetail']"><i
                   class="material-icons">border_color</i>
               </a></td> -->
             </tr>
             <!-- <tr *ngIf="!list || list.length <= 0">
                   <td colspan="4" align="center"> No data found. </td>
             </tr> -->
           </tbody>
            <tfoot>
             <tr>
               <td colspan="3">
                <mfBootstrapPaginator [rowsOnPageSet]="[10,25,50]"></mfBootstrapPaginator>
               </td>
             </tr>
           </tfoot>
        </table>
```

currently the one that appears is only on the user list that I wrote in []

this is my json

```
{
  "status": true,
  "data": {
    "id": "-LhKgaOz90Rg21Y_PCxz",
    "address": [],
    "age": 23,
    "company": "",
    "createdAt": "2019-06-14T11:14:43.318Z",
    "referredBy": "",
    "referredUser": {
        "total": 5,
        "list": [
            {
                "id": "-LhidpFKI86szc92Tu_X",
                "name": "john",
                "status": "ACTIVE"
            },
            {
                "id": "-LhizE4bQiliDv_PjLxk",
                "name": "doe",
                "status": "ACTIVE"
            },
            {
                "id": "-LhkOpj5tDNhHeiCm4S8",
                "name": "jane",
                "status": "ACTIVE"
            },
            {
                "id": "-LhkQPJ5hhLJlsbtnpnr",
                "name": "doe",
                "status": "ACTIVE"
            },
            {
                "id": "-LhmZVyBWbC6ceERUdjC",
                "name": "frend",
                "status": "INACTIVE"
            }
        ]
    },
    "socialAbout": "-",
    "socialProfession": "Event organizer"
  }
}
```

this is my ts

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from '@service/api.service';
import { Helper } from '@common/helper';
import * as AppConfig from '../../../environments/AppConfig';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-influencerrank',
  templateUrl: './influencerrank.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./influencerrank.component.css']
})
export class InfluencerrankComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(public apiService: ApiService,
        public helper: Helper
    ) {
        this.appConfig = AppConfig;
    }
    public sortBy: 'createdAt';
    public sortOrder: 'desc';
    public appConfig: any;
    users: any;
    public mainUsers: any;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.apiService.postCall(this.apiService.usersList, { 'startFrom': '' }, (response) => {
            if (response.status === true) {
                this.mainUsers = response.data;
                this.users = response.data.filter((item: any) => item.userType === 'LEADER');
        });
            } 
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<tr *ngFor="let user of mf.data.referredUser.list">
  <td>
    {{ user.name | titlecase }}
  </td>

  <td>
    {{ user.status }}
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: after I execute there is an error like this :

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngFor' since it's not a known property of 'tr'. ("<tr * ngFor =" let user.referredUser.list [0] of mf.data; let i = index "> ->
                     <tr [ERROR ->] * ngFor = "user of mf.data.referredUser.list">

Comment: Oops.. I missed let before user. Updated answer.

Comment: so far is still not successful
this error appears:
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read undefined 'list' property

Comment: @MuhammadArifinNursalim why is list undefined ? or is referredUser is undefined ? check your json. Also, I see you have updated your ts now. And I see this.users. Do you want to loop these users  ?

Comment: Yes, I intend to do a loop on json and then insert it into the table. so that later it is expected in the table to get dynamic data for names and status.

Comment: Please do console log of mf.data and post here the json.

Comment: {
    "status": true,
    "data": [
        {
            "birthDate": "1984-03-04T00:00:00.000Z",
            "birthPlace": "Jakarta",
            "createdAt": "2019-01-11T01:55:18.254Z",
            "gender": "female",
            "id": "-LVubjI0TYQOoa3uE06L",
            "totalReferredUser": 5
        }
    ]
}

this is the result of my JSON response. I want the results of the response to be like mine in POSTMAN. The POSTMAN results are JSON that I shared above.